# Is it possible to add as link NLog.config file?

Tags: nlog

I use NLog 4.4.12, .NET 4.5.2
I am trying to add NLog.config file as link, but then no logs are logged.
Is it possible to add as link NLog.config file?

Comment: Maybe is another way how to share NLog.config between multiple projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, but it's important to enable "copy to output directory"

[image]